# Parse an array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, ampersand.js

For highcharts, I need to generate parse data in order to generate series.
The data from API looks like this :

```
[ date : XX,
  series : [
            player_id : 1,
            team_id : 1,
            score : 4 ],
            [
            player_id : 2,
            team_id : 4,
            score : 1 ],
            [
            player_id : 4,
            team_id : 1,
            score : 4 ]

],
[ date : XX+1 
  series : ...
], 
...
```

First, the user have to select a team and players, but sometimes there is no result. For example, for the date XX, I selected 4 team ID but the API returns only 2 of them. I have to take this in consideration.
I'm trying to different types of series, the first one represents all the team scores, the second one all the players scores, and the other for the score each team did. So there are many graphs.

I'm using Ampserand.js, the the model is the same but he is called as much time as the number of teams selected in the form.

I did something like this:

```
function parse(data) {
    var series = [];
    var dates = [];
    var findIndexByValue = function(arraytosearch, key, valuetosearch) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arraytosearch.length; i++) {
            if (arraytosearch[i][key] == valuetosearch) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dTemp = new Date(data[i].date).getTime();

        // Keep dates in case of empty values
        dates.push(dTemp);

        for (var s = 0; s < data[i].series.length; s++) {
            var current = data[i].series[s];

            if (this.currentype === "allTeamSeries") {
                var currentIndex = findIndexByValue(series, "team", current.team_id);

                if (currentIndex === null) {
                    series.push({
                        team: current.team_id,
                        data: [dTemp, current.avg]
                    });
                } else {
                    series[currentIndex].data.push([dTemp, current.score]);
                }
            } else if (this.currentResource === "playerseries") {
                var currentIndex = findIndexByValue(series, "player", current.player_id);

                if (currentIndex === null) {
                    series.push({
                        player: current.player_id,
                        data: [dTemp, current.score]
                    });

                } else {
                    series[currentIndex].data.push([dTemp, current.score]);
                }
            } else { //currentTeam from model
                if (this.currentTeam === current.team_id) {
                    var currentIndex = findIndexByValue(series, "site", current.site_id);

                    if (currentIndex === null) {
                        series.push({
                            team: current.team_id,
                            data: [dTemp, current.score]
                        });
                    } else {
                        series[currentIndex].data.push([dTemp, current.score]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // Avoid empty charts
    if (series.length === 0) {
        series.push({
            team: this.currentTeam,
            data: []
        });

        dates.forEach(function(elem) {
            series[0].data.push([elem, 0]);
        });
    }

    return {
        startdate: this.config.startdate,
        enddate: this.config.enddate,
        series: series
    };
}
```

I have a problem with the series generated when there is no result for a team in the api's result.

An usable array should be like this for example :

```
series: [{
    name: 'Team 1',
    data: [4163, 5203, 6276, 5408, 3547, 3729, 3828,4163, 5203, 6276, 5408, 3547, 3729, 3828,4163, 5203, 6276, 5408, 3547, 3729, 3828]
    }, 
    {
    name: 'Team 2',
    data: [...]
 }]
```

Moreover, the code looks redundant, is there a trick with some Array function to do that more easily ?

Thanks in advance, big problem for me here !

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work for you? I just tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/5/ - looks strange.

Anyway, I would suggest to improve a bit your `if-else` statements, for example:

```
            var currentIndex = findIndexByValue(series, "team", current.team_id);

            if (currentIndex === null) {
                series.push({
                    team: current.team_id,
                    data: [dTemp, current.avg]
                });
            } else {
                series[currentIndex].data.push([dTemp, current.score]);
            }
```

This can be made as one function:

```
function manageSeries (series, name, key, xVal, yValName) {
            var currentIndex = findIndexByValue(series, name, current[key]),
                seriesObj = {};

            if (currentIndex === null) {
                seriesObj[name] = current[key];
                seriesObj.data = [dTemp, current[yValName]];
                series.push(seriesObj);
            } else {
                series[currentIndex].data.push([dTemp, current[yValName]);
            }
}
```

Now simply:

```
if (this.currentype === "allTeamSeries") {
    manageSeries(series, 'team', 'team_id', dTemp, 'avg');
else if (this.currentResource === "playerseries") {
    manageSeries(series, 'player', 'player_id', dTemp, 'score');
} else if (this.currentTeam === current.team_id) {
    manageSeries(series, 'site', 'site_id', dTemp, 'score');
}
```

Note: Code is not tested, because I couldn't setup working demo according to the info you provided, sorry.